# Effective hamiltonian method for the quantum Ising model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, phase-transition, perturbation-theory, ising-model

I am reading Subir Sachdevs book on quantum phase transitions (second edition). In chapter 5 (page 58) he defines a hamiltonian 
$H=H_0+H_1$ where the eigenstates of $H_0$ are known and the influence of $H_1$ is described by perturbation theory. The spectrum of $H_0$ is such that the eigenvalues can be separated into distinct groups of closely spaced levels.The energy gap between two levels within a group is much smaller than the energy gap between levels in two distinct groups. The idea of the effective hamiltonian method is to perform a unitary transformation on $H$ to get a hamiltonian $H_{eff}$ such that the inter group matrix elements of $H_{eff}$ vanish. $H_{eff}$ is defined order by order in $H$. I don't understand how $H_{eff}$ is written order by order as: \begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\left\langle i, \alpha\left|H_{\mathrm{eff}}\right| j, \alpha\right\rangle=& E_{i \alpha} \delta_{i j}+\left\langle i, \alpha\left|H_{1}\right| j, \alpha\right\rangle \\
&+\sum_{k, \beta \neq \alpha} \frac{\left\langle i, \alpha\left|H_{1}\right| k, \beta\right\rangle\left\langle k, \beta\left|H_{1}\right| j, \alpha\right\rangle}{2}\left(\frac{1}{E_{i \alpha}-E_{k \beta}}+\frac{1}{E_{j, \alpha}-E_{k \beta}}\right).
\end{aligned}\end{equation} 
where $\alpha$ is group index and $i,j$ are levels within the group.

Comment: There is a derivation in Section 2.2 and Appendix A of Avan, Cohen-Tannoudji, Dupont-Roc, Fabre, Journal de Physique, 37 (9) (1976) (PDF): https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/710f/de4b56a2c9286aa1e2cf185eef3f638d7f70.pdf

Comment: Thank you.Will check it out